# Como cargar un assembly usando la reflexión en C#

Tags: c#

Hola mi pregunta es como puedo cargar un assembly ya sea una dll o binario usando la reflexión, normalmente para cargar un assembly lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
//Load the bytes as an assembly
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer);

//Execute the assembly
object[] parameters = new object[1];                
exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Pero ahora estaba intentandolo usando la reflexión para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load").Invoke(null,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
```

Cuando lo hago del primer modo funciona bien. Pero cuando uso el siguiente método(usando solo reflexión) me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
    typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load").Invoke(null,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Proof.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 591f941f
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1590.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5787ed44
  Problem Signature 07: 1037
  Problem Signature 08: 60
  Problem Signature 09: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatch
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    3082
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

A que se debe este error? Pregunto porque he visto varios artículos relacionados con esto y quería entender porque en este caso porque no ha funcionado.

Estaba intentando llamar al assembly load usando la reflexión pero no entiendo porque una versión si funciona y la otra no como podría compatibizarla para que funcionase / cargando el assembly load de modo reflectivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que [el método `Assembly.Load` tiene multiples sobrecargas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx).  La sobrecarga que tu desea es [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx).  Puede cargar un assembly usando la reflexión, [usar `GetMethod(string name, Type[] types)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var assemblyBytes = /* ... */;
var loadMethod = typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[]) });
var newAssembly = loadMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { assemblyBytes });
```

Ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo que muestra un Assembly cargado]

O invocar un exe:

```
var assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("ReflectionAssemblyLoadTarget.exe");
var loadMethod = typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[]) });
var newAssembly = loadMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { assemblyBytes });

((Assembly)newAssembly).EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
```

Comment: Sé que esto codigo funciona. ¿Hay otras diferencias? Yo examinaría [Fusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) o [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) si no tiene ninguna excepciones.

Comment: ¡Ah!  El codigo que proporcioné solo carga el assembly.  Necesitas invocar el `EntryPoint` tambien.

Comment: claro exactamente esolo que intentaba .. gracias